# Is it possible to create a generic type in Oracle, one that is suitable to many data domains?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Is there a way to create a generic type in Oracle which accepts data from different domains (as numbers and texts)?

OR

Is there a way to create a **VARRAY** of **REF**, being the REF a reference to different types of objects.

Something like this:

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LIST_REFS AS VARRAY(10) OF REF

Is it possible?

Comment: varchar2 accepts text, number, and dates.  It simply stores them as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Oracle has an ANYDATA type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_anydat.htm#ARPLS71602) which is intended for use as a generic type to hold data of different types. [It's a little awkward to use](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1853).